# sum of even numbers within 1-100 using FOR LOOP

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum

None of the codes I found used a for loop which is what was requested, no other options are valid.

```py
    total = 0 #defined total
    for number in range(1,101): #set a for loop with a range between (1-101)
        if number %2 == 0:  #if number(1-101) is divisible by 2 == 0
            total = sum(int(number)) #TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
            print(total) # expected result is to print 2550
```

Comment: FWIW, you don't even need a loop to solve this: `sum(range(0, 101, 2))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use python built-in function `sum`.

```
sum(range(0, 101, 2))
```

Comment: https://www.hackinscience.org/exercises/sum-of-even-numbers-below-100   you're welcome to try, but it doesn't appear to be working.